# Is (int32_t) 255 << 24 undefined behavior in gcc (C++11)?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, bit-shift

In C++11, according to [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators),

> For signed and non-negative a, the value of a << b is
>   *a * 2<sup>b</sup>* if it is representable in the return type,
>   otherwise the behavior is undefined.

My understanding is that, since 255 * 2<sup>24</sup> is not
representable as an `int32_t`, the evaluation of `(int32_t) 255 << 24`
yields undefined behavior. Is that correct? Can this be
compiler-dependent? It's an IP16 environment, if that matters.

Background: this comes from [an argument I am having](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/59809/7508) with a
user at arduino.stackexchange.com. According to him, “there's nothing
undefined about that at all”:

> you notice that much of the bit shifting is "implementation defined".
>   So you cannot quote chapter-and-verse from the specs. You have to go
>   to the GCC documentation since that is the only place that can tell
>   you what actually happens.
>   [gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Bit-Shifting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Bit-Shifting) -
>   it's only "undefined" for a negative shift value.

---

**Edit**: From the answers so far, it would seem my reading of *the
C++11 standard* is correct. Then the key part of my question is whether
this expression invokes undefined behavior **in gcc**. As davmac puts it
in his comment, I am asking “whether GCC, an implementation, defines a
behaviour even though it is left undefined by the language standard”.

From the gcc manual I linked to, it would seem it is indeed defined,
although I find the wording of this manual sounds more like a tutorial
than a “language law”. From PSkocik's answer (and Kane's comment to that
answer), it would instead seem it is undefined. So I am still in doubt.

I guess my dream would be to have a clear statement in some gcc
documentation stating either that 1) gcc does not define any behavior
that is explicitly undefined in the standard or, 2) gcc does define this
behavior from version XX.XX and commits to keep it defined in all
subsequent versions.

**Edit 2**: PSkocik deleted his answer, which I find unfortunate because
it provided interesting information. From his answer, Kane's comment to
the answer, and my own experiments:

1. `(int32_t)255<<24` produces a runtime error when compiled with clang
   and `-fsanitize=undefined`
2. the same code produces no error with g++ even with
   `-fsanitize=undefined`
3. `(int32_t)256<<24` does give a runtime error when compiled with
   `g++ -std=c++11 -fsanitize=undefined`

Point 2 is consistent with the interpretation that gcc, in C++11 mode,
defines the left shift more broadly than the standard. As per point 3,
this definition could just be the C++14 definition. However, point 3 is
*inconsistent* with the idea that [the referenced manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Bit-Shifting) is a
complete definition of `<<` in gcc (C++11 mode), as that manual provides
no hint that `(int32_t)256<<24` could be undefined.

Comment: "undefined behavior is something for which the standard imposes no requirements." which means it can even be the expected/correct behavior. And a compiler might do just that within certain constraints. As per your link, GCC wanted to make it undefined for negative values only.

Comment: The GNU C reference says: _"For both << and >>, if the second operand is greater than the bit-width of the first operand, or the second operand is negative, the behavior is undefined"_. To some degree this implies that then answer to your question is "yes". But, this might not have been intended to be exhaustive; it is not explicitly stated, and I think it would be dangerous to assume that "yes" is the answer.

Comment: Also note that the GNU C reference documents C and not C++.

Comment: The C(++)-standard quotation you posted states quite clearly it's UB so why do you question it over something somebody on the Internet has said?

Comment: @PSkocik to me it's clear that OP is asking whether GCC, an implementation, defines a behaviour even though it is left undefined by the language standard.

Comment: You are both correct.  On an Arduino it will have a predictable and repeatable value.  But the C++ standard will not tell you what that value will be.  Another common place where you'd find code using UB intentionally is in a CRT implementation.

Comment: @HansPassant: Re “it will have a predictable and repeatable value”: I am still looking for a convincing argument that this is true, within the current _and all future_ Arduino environments. I am willing to take for granted that Arduino will stick with gcc, but not with a specific version of gcc.

Answer (score 8):

This changed over time, and with good reason, so let's go through the history. Note that in all cases, simply doing `static_cast<int>(255u << 24)` has always been defined behavior. Maybe just do that and side-step all problems.

---

The original [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.shift) wording was:

> The value of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1×2E2`, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. Otherwise, if `E1` has a signed type and non-negative value, and `E1×2E2` is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

`255 << 24` is undefined behavior in C++11 because the resulting value is unrepresentable as a 32-bit signed integer, it is too large.

This undefined behavior causes some issues because `constexpr` *must* diagnose undefined behavior - and so some common approaches to setting values led to hard errors. Hence [CWG 1457](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1457):

> The current wording of 8.8 [expr.shift] paragraph 2 makes it undefined behavior to create the most-negative integer of a given type by left-shifting a (signed) 1 into the sign bit, even though this is not uncommonly done and works correctly on the majority of (twos-complement) architectures [...] As a result, this technique cannot be used in a constant expression, which will break a significant amount of code.

This was a defect applied against C++11. Technically, a conforming C++11 compiler would implement all of the defect reports, and so it would be correct to say that in C++11, this is *not* undefined behavior; the behavior for `255 << 24` in C++11 is defined to be `-16777216`.

The post-defect wording can be seen in [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.shift):

> The value of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1×2E2`, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. Otherwise, if `E1` has a signed type and non-negative value, and `E1×2E2` is representable in the **corresponding unsigned type of the** result type, then that **value, converted to the result type,** is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

There were no changes to the wording/behavior in C++17.

But for C++20, as a result of the [Signed Integers are Two's Complement](https://wg21.link/p0907) (and its [wording paper](https://wg21.link/p1236)), the wording is [greatly simplified](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift):

> The value of `E1 << E2` is the unique value congruent to `E1×2E2` modulo `2N`, where `N` is the range exponent of the type of the result.

`255 << 24` still has defined behavior in C++20 (with the same resulting value), it's just that the specification for how we get there becomes a lot simpler because the language doesn't have to work around the fact that the representation for signed integers was implementation-defined.

Comment: Prior to SFINAE, there wasn't a perceived need to care about fine distinctions between actions for which the Standard mandated a behavior, versus those where all commonplace implementations would do the same thing with or without a mandate.  I don't think there was ever any intention on the part of the Standard to encourage or require implementations to process shifts in anything other than the manner mandated by C89, but things have nonetheless managed to beat around the bush a great deal before arriving exactly where they started.

Comment: Thank-you for this very interesting background! It still leaves open the question of whether gcc defines `255<<24` as an extension to C++11.

Comment: CWG1457 is a DR.

Comment: @T.C. So the right thing is to say that C++11 actually defines this behavior too?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the correct interpretation: a hypothetical perfect compiler's C++11 mode should treat it as defined.

Answer (score 3):

"Undefined behavior is something for which the standard imposes no requirements." which means it can even be the expected/correct behavior. That C++ standard states with respect to shift operators.

> **8.5.7 Shift operators [expr.shift]** (C++ Standard draft N4713)
>
> 1. The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. The behavior is undeﬁned if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.  Otherwise, if `E1` has a signed type and non-negative value, and `E1×2E2` is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned.

As @rustyx notes below, "The wording "`E1×2E2` is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type" is [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr#shift-2). Still UB in [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr#shift-2) unfortunately."

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, though. If these were the only ways that a shift can have undefined behaviour, then the answer to OP's question would be "no"; but it's not clear from this quote whether that is the case.

Comment: (Significantly, you missed: _Otherwise, if
E1
has a signed type and non-negative value, and
E1
×
2
E2
is representable
in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the
resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined_).

Comment: @davmac: Added that now. The OP seemed to know that part already, so did not add it initially.

Comment: The wording "E1×2E2 is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type" is [C++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr#shift-2). Still UB in [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr#shift-2) unfortunately.

Comment: Of course. Please do. BTW signed integer overflow will be entirely well-defined in C++20 (finally the committee is convinced there is only two's complement arithmetic).

Comment: Sorry, I grabbed the right paragraph from the wrong version of the document. Yes, it's undefined - that was what was critically missing. (But also I think just quoting the standard still misses the point of the question).

Comment: @rustyx unless you know something I don't (which is possible!), signed overflow will still be undefined behaviour in C++20 despite mandating a 2's complement representation for integers. See the revision notes for the proposal at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r4.html

Comment: @davmac thanks for pointing to the proposal. I stand corrected. I only looked up the last wording on [expr.shift/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#2) which appeared promising.

Comment: @davmac: It's unfortunate that the Standard doesn't provide any means via which implementations can promise to support some of the most useful guarantees that flowed from silent-wraparound behavior, e.g. guaranteeing that integer operators (other than compound-assignment operators) will have no side-effects except for possibly triggering an implementation-defined trap.  In many cases, guaranteeing that an operation will yield a certain specific result may be expensive, but guaranteeing that it will proceed without side-effects would cost essentially nothing.

Answer (score 3):

The GNU **C** compiler defines the left/right shifts fully as described in the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation):

> *GCC supports only two’s complement integer types, and all bit patterns are ordinary values.*
>
> . . .
>
> *As an extension to the C language, GCC does not use the latitude given in C99 and C11 only to treat certain aspects of signed ‘`<<`’ as undefined. However, `-fsanitize=shift` (and `-fsanitize=undefined`) will diagnose such cases. They are also diagnosed where constant expressions are required.*

So that's consistent with your findings - the code does what you expect, only an overflow beyond the available bits (including the sign bit) will be diagnosed.

As for the GNU **C++** compiler, the documentation seems to be really [lacking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Implementation.html#C_002b_002b-Implementation). We can only guess that by omission the shift works in G++ the same way it does in GCC, although at least the [sanitizer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-ftrapv) appears to be aware of the language differences:

> `-fsanitize=shift`
>
> This option enables checking that the result of a shift operation is not undefined. Note that what exactly is considered undefined differs slightly between C and C++, as well as between ISO C90 and C99, etc.

Comment: That's quite interesting, but I am not sure I understand what specific aspects of `<<` the manual refers to by “certain aspects”. It's a pity that the gcc manual does not document the C++ implementation as thoroughly as C.

Comment: The way I read it is that GCC gives no special meaning to the sign bit. So there is no difference between signed and unsigned shifts.

Comment: I find it interesting that gcc regards continued support for behavior that had been unambiguously defined under C89 as an "extension", especially given that the C99 Rationale gives no indication whatsoever that they intended to suggest any change to how two's-complement implementations without padding bits should process the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For C++ compilers prior to C++14, if you had a function like this:

```
// check if the input is still positive,
// after a suspicious shift

bool test(int input)
{
    if (input > 0) 
    {
        input = input << 24;

        // how can this become negative in C++11,
        // unless you are relying on UB?

        return (input > 0); 
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

then an optimizing compiler would have been allowed to change it into this:

```
bool test(int input)
{
    // unless you are relying on UB, 
    // input << 24 must fit into an int,
    // and input is positive in that branch

    return (input > 0);
}
```

And everyone is happy because you get a nice speedup in your release builds.

I am, however, not aware of compilers which actually do such optimizations for left-shifts, although it's quite common for additions to be optimized away, as [seen in this example](https://godbolt.org/z/DDvHX0).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am already aware of this. I already tried, unsuccessfully, to get gcc optimize out `if (x>=0 && (x<<24)<0) ...`.

Comment: Oh, ok then, I was under the impression that you can compile for arduino using different compilers (there are people using [rust](https://github.com/avr-rust/rust), after all), but if this is g++ specific, then standards are basically irrelevant.

Comment: I guess you could use different compilers, but as the Arduino environment uses gcc, it is the “Arduino standard compiler” of sorts. And the C++11 standard is still relevant insofar as gcc is supposed to be a “compliant implementation”.

Comment: Well, FWIW, your argument in the linked thread is valid, [this code](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/59809/52177) is UB under C++11. It isn't portable, and a future version of gcc might (theoretically) break it with `-std=c++11`. I say theoretically because programmers are so used to disregarding the standards that such a change would probably break huge amounts of existing code. And the solution is just a cast to `uint32_t` and back, so I don't see why the guy is against making it portable. I would compare it to forcing the use of gcc builtins instead of standard portable constructs.

Comment: Most overflow-related optimizations could be enabled by saying that compilers are allowed to process signed arithmetic using arbitrary extended integer types of their choosing in the absence of type conversions or casts.  Many of the rest could be enabled by allowing compilers to also extend the length of storage used for signed-integer-type objects whose address is not taken.  Even if code is intended for use only with `-fwrapv` or equivalent, adding a cast like `if ((int)(x << y) < 0)` would make the meaning of the code clearer to a human, so...

Comment: ...having a compiler optimize `(x<<y)<0` to `x<0` when there is no cast wouldn't break a huge amount of code, even if that code was targeting simple compilers that could only generate optimal code if given an expression that shifts left and tests the sign bit (since such code should include a cast anyway).  A bigger problem is with compilers where integer arithmetic might not only behave as though it produces results larger than `int`, but it might have arbitrary side-effects on the surrounding code.